# How to stop camel standalone app in the proper way

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have developed a standalone  apache camel application(version 2.13) using the spring DSL, the application is launched witha shell script: java-cp ... MAIN_CLASS and everything works perfectly, the problem I can not find an elegant way to stop the application. Currently I use Ctrl-C or kill -9.

I would like to create another script which execute java class that stop camel using camelContext.stop(). But if I create a new script I have no access to the camel context created by the first script(two different JVM instances) . 
Have you any suggestions for solving this problematic. All your comments and suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: Do you see message camel route is shutting down in the log? You need configure log level info for camel package. If yes, then your camel route is shutting down properly

Comment: No, camel is not stopped because i can't acces the camelContext created using the first script

Comment: What I mean is Ctrl -c , did you see shutdown message?

Answer (score 0):

Put a shutdown hook in your java code calling camelContext.stop(). Then trigger this by sending SIGTERM to the process (kill -15). To keep track of the PID, record it in the start script and put it in a PID-file.